# nbconvert: ValueError: No template sub-directory with name 'rst' found in the following paths: [LS OF PATHS]

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, restructuredtext, nbconvert

I am using `nbconvert` to convert markdown file to pdf. In the code I used `writer = nbconvert.RSTExporter()` but when render the result with `writer.from_notebook_node()`, I faced the error:

```
ValueError: No template sub-directory with name 'rst' found in the following paths:
/Users/hoanguyen/Library/Jupyter
/Users/hoanguyen/miniconda3/envs/d2l-book/share/jupyter #this is my current environment
/usr/local/share/jupyter
/usr/share/jupyter
```

The code can be seen here: https://github.com/d2l-ai/d2l-book/blob/dev/d2lbook/build.py#L653-L657

I installed `nbconvert`, pandoc with [this instruction](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) and I did have `Tex` installed as well.

How can I install `rst` template for `nbconvert`? Please help me suggest some workarounds for this issue?

System information:

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.1
python: 3.6
nbconvert: 6.0.0a3
pandoc: 1.0.2
```

Comment: You can install an older version of nbconvert, for a similar error 5.6.1 works for me.

Comment: this saved me as well. Thank you @Joost

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some unknown reason, the versions from 6.0.0 and on don't include the templates. A workaround is to download them manually from older versions in the repository. (e.g. [v5.6.1](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/tree/5.6.1/nbconvert/templates))