# No template sub-directory with name 'lab' found in the following paths

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, azure-functions, jupyter, nbconvert

I am running a python azure function which is running a jupyter notebook via the `nbconvert` API. This was working for a time, although without deploying new code I have started to get the following error:

```
No template sub-directory with name 'lab' found in the following paths:
    /home/.local/share/jupyter
    /usr/local/share/jupyter
    /usr/share/jupyter
```

The code I am using to achieve this is:

```
from nbconvert.preprocessors import ExecutePreprocessor
from nbconvert import HTMLExporter

...

dl = DictLoader({'footer':
"""
{%- extends 'full.tpl' -%}

{% block input_group %}
    {%- if cell.metadata.get('nbconvert', {}).get('show_code', False) -%}
        ((( super() )))
    {%- endif -%}
{% endblock input_group %}
{% block output_group %}
    <style> .output_prompt{visibility:hidden;}</style>
    {{ super() }}
{% endblock output_group %}
"""})

...

html_exporter = HTMLExporter(extra_loaders=[dl], template_file='footer')
html_exporter.template_name = 'classic'
with open(JUPYTER_DIR + NOTEBOOK_NAME) as f:
    nb = nbformat.read(f, as_version=4)

ep = ExecutePreprocessor(timeout=600, kernel_name='python')
ep.preprocess(nb, {'metadata': {'path': JUPYTER_DIR}})
(body, resources) = html_exporter.from_notebook_node(nb)
```

The functionapp is running the following:

```
python3.6
nbconvert6.0.3
jupyter-lab0.1.1
```

I have tried googling the error, the closest thing I have found so far is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62431121/nbconvert-valueerror-no-template-sub-directory-with-name-rst-found-in-the-fo) which is similar but unanswered and not completely the same. Thought I'd post here to see if anyone knows how to resolve or for me to update if I manage to resolve the issue.

I am quite confused as `lab` is not a keyword I am familiar with (outside of maybe `jupyterlab`) and isn't being used within the code.

As for the paths mentioned:

- `home/.local/share/jupyter/` exists and contains `nbconvert/templates/html`
- `usr/local/share/jupyter` & `usr/share/jupyter` don't exist

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue after upgrading nbconvert to 6.0.8.

Rolling back to nbconvert 5.6.1 solved the problem for me.

> `pip uninstall nbconvert` 
> `pip install nbconvert==5.6.1`

Answer (score 14):

For me, uninstalling and installing nbconvert using:

```
pip uninstall nbconvert
pip install nbconvert
```

fixed this error.

Answer (score 8):

On Mac, if you installed jupyter using pip3 on user mode

```
ln -s ~/Library/Python/3.8/share/jupyter/nbconvert ~/Library/Jupyter/nbconvert
```

Just replace the 3.8 with the approriate version

Answer (score 7):

`pip install -U nbconvert` installs
`.../site-packages/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/` 
but `jupyter nbconvert my.ipynb --to python` doesn't look there --

```
# ValueError: No template sub-directory with name 'base' found in the following paths:

/Users/myuserid/Library/Jupyter  # mac
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/share/jupyter
/usr/local/share/jupyter
/usr/share/jupyter
```

Make a symbolic link in one of these to `.../site-packages/.../templates`, e.g.

```
cd $HOME/Library/Jupyter/nbconvert  # mac, other platforms dunno
mv templates templates-tmp  # empty
ln -s .../site-packages/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates .
ls templates/
# asciidoc/  classic/      html/  latex/     python/  rst/
# base/    compatibility/  lab/   markdown/  reveal/  script/
```

Comment: On Windows 10 the template files were installed at: C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Python\share\jupyter\nbconvert

I copied them to: C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\nbconvert\templates

Comment: @JeremyWhitcher Your comment solved my problem. I genuinely thank you.

Comment: @JeremyWhitcher Many thanks. Your advice helped me to download a notebook as an HTML-file.

Answer (score 6):

On Mac, very similar to @denis solution, just the locations are diffferent:

```
cd /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/share/jupyter/nbconvert/
mv templates templates-tmp
ln -s /opt/homebrew/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates
```

Comment: This worked in my case, except just had to create the `jupyter/nbconvert/` directory in `share` since it didn't already exist.

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting the same exact error.  I am assuming the default/built in templates were just installed during anaconda installation.  I think we have to look at older versions of jupyter notebook / nbconvert / anaconda and just copy and paste the template files.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your installation locations you might want to adjust "path" and "target" variables below. In my case (Windows 10 with python installed from the Microsoft store and jupyter via pip) the following resolved the issue with jupyter not finding nbconvert. You will need to use ***elevated power shell (PS)*** to create link in APPDATA

```
PS > $path=$env:APPDATA+"\jupyter\nbconvert"
PS > $target=$env:LOCALAPPDATA+"\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\share\jupyter\nbconvert"
PS > New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -path "$path" -target "$target"
```

This should create link in appropriate location

Answer (score 2):

Had the same Issue (Mac Monterey 12.01)

Download nbconvert from GitHub and install solved it for me :
Based on : https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert

- *git clone https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert.git*
- *cd nbconvert*
- *pip install -e .*